# Splitting rows into columns with group by clause

Tags: sql-server, linq

I have three tables Lab, Payments and Transaction

[image]

I want to spilt transType into two columns, sum TransType Group By BillId and compare it with Lab.TotalBill to get Refundable Payments/Due payments
I need SQL Query or LINQ Query please

Comment: Could you show the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly, what you are asking but this should do the first part:

```
SELECT BillID
,SUM(case when TransType = 'Received' OR TransType = 'Recieved' then 1 end) AS 'Number of Received'
,SUM(case when TransType = 'Refunded' then 1 else 0 end) AS 'Number of Refunded'
FROM [H+Active].[dbo].[Transactions]
GROUP BY BillID
```

Comment: I need following fields in resultsBillId, Patientname, TotalBill, Discount, Received-amount, Pending-Amount or RefundableAmount

Comment: I need following fields in results 
BillId, Patientname, TotalBill, Discount, Received-amount, Pending-Amount or RefundableAmount

Comment: In that case you could process the data in the Transactions table into a temporary table to get the total received/pending/refundable for each BillId, then just join the tables.